# Establish the existence of a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to show that for any nonzero integer $n$ there exists a unique group homomorphism $U(\mathbb{Z}/4n\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \{\pm1\}$ possessing the property that for any odd prime $p$ not dividing $n$, $\overline{p}\mapsto\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)$ under this mapping?

Also, is there any "intuitive" version of this statement? What it is all about?

Comment: "What it is all about?" I suppose, it is about number theory, in particular about the Legendre symbol, and quadratic Dirichlet characters. From which class is it?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: you're right, it's number theory, but I was hoping that it might be a veiled version of a well-known fact which may be stated in less abstract terms.

Comment: This depends on the context. You have not answered yet, what the context is. So it is difficult to help you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: by saying "it's about number theory" I meant in particular that this is a problem from (an introductory) course in number theory.

Comment: Does it treat Dirichlet characters? What book are you following?

Comment: Rather it's algebraic number theory. It is supposed to end on Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions. I don't know whether it is connected to Dirichlet characters. As for the book, there is no one upon which the course is based. At present I only use handwritten lecture notes.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that for $n$ odd the group $U(\mathbb{Z}/4n)$ is isomorphic to the group $\{\pm 1\}\times U(\mathbb{Z}/n)$, and that the Legendre symbol is a homomorphism $\chi\colon U(\mathbb{Z}/n)\rightarrow \{\pm 1\}$, defined by $\chi(n)=(n/p)$, which has order $2$, i.e., $\chi^2=\chi_1$, the identity of the character group.